# Access ColdFusion session variables in React application

Tags: reactjs, coldfusion

I have a website in ColdFusion and I'm adding new features developed in React to this website.

I include a `<div>` in my ColdFusion website:

```
<div id="addReact"></div>
```

Then, I build my React application to run in this div.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('addReact')
);
```

Also, I include the js and css files generated from the `npm run build` to my ColdFusion website.

It works perfectly. However, I would like to access ColdFusion session variables in my React application. For example, I have `session.userId` in my ColdFusion website. How can I access it in the React application?

My first idea was setting in the website a hidden input with the userId. `<input type="hidden" id="userID" value="#session.userId#"/>` and access it in React with JQuery. I believe it is not safe. Is there a better way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as it not being safe, anything you send to the front end, no matter how or when you do it, needs to be “safe”. A userID isn’t necessarily not safe.

Comment: @Redtopia my safety concern is regarding the client being able to change the ```<input>``` value with the browser inspector. Maybe I could encrypt it, I'm just checking if there is a better solution

Comment: There are at least two ways to pass values from CF to JS.  One is the `ToScript()` function and the other is the `<cfwddx>` tag.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you, but it's not what I need. It pass the CF variable to a ```<script></script>``` JavaScript code, not to a React component.

Comment: Passing the UserId to a client isn't inherently insecure.  I would consider the use case.  If you just need to pass that value back to the server in an AJAX request you really shouldn't need to pass anything at all.  The browser should automatically provide your CFID and CFTOKEN cookie values when running AJAX requests which will allow your server-side code to access the correct session normally.  You can also always pass the CFID and CFTOKEN values.  If you still find yourself needing to store the data on the client then a hidden input or custom attribute is as "secure" as any other method.

Comment: As @JasonHolden said, you might not need a userID if you can get it for your currently logged in user on the ajax request. This assumes you're storing it somewhere in the user's session. The CFID/CFTOKEN pair are pulled from your cookies or request headers automatically by ColdFusion and will map the request to your session variables.

Comment: Is it possible to get the session content by the CFID?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532, CFID and CFTOKEN cookies are used by ColdFusion to map the user's session. Depending on how you have your app configured, and if the session scope is enabled, then ColdFusion automatically gets your session for you and you access it via the `Session Scope`.